# Getting the "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" warning

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System. Numeric;   //meant to be numeric with an s at the end but stack overflow also whined
using System. Security. Cryptography;
using System. Globalization;

class Program
{
    int Addition(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    int Multiplication(int num1, int num2)
    { 
        return num1 * num2;
    }

    int Subtraction(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }

    int Division(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 / num2;
    }

    public int Main()
    {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int answer = 0;

        while (true)
        { 
            Console. WriteLine("What is your first number? ");
            string a = Console. Read Line();
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(a);
            Console. WriteLine("What operator do you want to use? ");
            string b = Console. Read Line();
            Console. WriteLine("What is your second integer? ");
            string c = Console. Read Line();
            num2 = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            answer = Addition(num1, num2);
            answer = Multiplication(num1, num2);
            answer = Subtraction(num1, num2);
            answer = Division(num1, num2);
            Console. WriteLine("The answer is " + answer);
            if (b == "+")
            {
                int Addition;
            }
            else if (b == "*")
            {
                int Multiplication;
            }
            else if (b == "-")
            {
                int Subtraction;
            }
            else if (b == "/")
            {
                int Division;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding class program and doing public int main as that function needs access to the functions above. I just want help with fixing that error and not cleaning up my code.

Comment: `Main` must be `static`; it seems that you should make all the rest methods `static` as well. https://dotnetfiddle.net/kOwAMD

Comment: Furthermore you surely don't want to calculate **all** four answers on each iteration, but just that one that fits the operator. So just add that `answer`stuff into the appropriate if-statement.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error

> Can someone help, my code keeps whining about "Program does not
> contain a ***static*** 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

So your main method needs to have the static declaration

```
static int Main()
{
    //... 

}
```

Then you will also have to make all the other methods static.

Also, you have it set to return `int` but it actually doesn't return anything.  So better to change it to `static void Main()`